# Request Attributes not clearing after request is over

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having a problem with request attributes in my jsp, I am using the mvc pattern and setting a request attribute and forwarding to a jsp from the servlet. The application is a banking application, the goal is to use the customer id to get the customer by customer id pass it to the Account class to collect all of the accounts of the user. I have this problem solved I can get the account information and process it without any issue. The problem I am having is when I close the page and run again from the beginning I find that when I get to the  table it is still putting in the information from the previous request as well as the new information that I am requesting. Like So:

([image: First Run])

[image: second Run]

My code is as follows for the servlet that directs me to the jsp and the jsp that I use the information into.

AccountServlet.java:

```
package com.ChattBank.controller;

import com.ChattBank.business.Account;
import com.ChattBank.business.Accounts;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author AARONS
 */
public class AccountServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet AccountServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet AccountServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action == null) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else if (action.equals("view")) {
            Accounts acct = new Accounts();
            ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList();
            try {
                acct.setCustAccounts(request.getParameter("id"));
                list.addAll(acct.getCustAccounts());
                System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Accounts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            request.setAttribute("acctList", list);
                request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/accounts.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } 

}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    String custId = request.getParameter("custID");

    if (action == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

accounts.jsp:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : accounts
    Created on : Jun 25, 2014, 12:24:38 AM
    Author     : Richard Davy
--%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.ChattBank.business.Account"%>
<%@page import="com.ChattBank.business.Accounts"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Your Accounts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <% 
            ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList();

            list.addAll((ArrayList)request.getAttribute("acctList"));

            for (Account custAccount : list) {
                System.out.println("From JSP: " + custAccount.getCustId() + " " + custAccount.getAcctNo() + " " + custAccount.getAcctType() + " " + custAccount.getBalance());
                System.out.println("Getting Object From Section");
            }        
        %>

        <h1>You Made It Here!</h1>
        <table border="1" width="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="10">Your Chatt Accounts</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){ %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Account: </td>
                    <td colspan="2"><%= list.get(i).getCustId() %></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><%= list.get(i).getAcctNo() %></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><%= list.get(i).getAcctType() %></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><%= list.get(i).getBalance() %></td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
                <% list.clear(); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            <p>Thank you for your business!</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am not really sure what is going on I started with session attributes and thought that was my issue, so I turned to using request attributes. But I am still facing the same issue. I was under the impression that the request attribute only lasted per that request but it seems that the information is still being carried through. Any suggestions?

Comment: As for your code, it will display the last request stored in the acctList... for each request new arrylist object will create and the request paramenter also will flush with new request id ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList(); and request.setAttribute("acctList", list);

Comment: @RajavelD I am not sure what you are getting at, I get that the request will store the last request, but it is continuing to hold on to those request indefinitely. It doesn't seem to be releasing any of the previous request information unless I remove the application from deployment and redeploy.

Comment: did you cleared the browser catch and checked ?

Comment: Request scope attributes are supposed to end at request.. you might have been facing some other problem.

Comment: @RajavelD yes if I clear the browser history the first operation of the application is fine but the next operation is the same result, the data still appears from the last request.

Comment: According to you, problem is in  list.addAll((ArrayList)request.getAttribute("acctList")); line .. right? as acclist attribute should not be there.

Comment: @abhijeet I thought so too, but that is why I am here because I can't seem to figure out the problem I am having.

Comment: @abhijeet yes, when I run the program the first time it runs fine, when I run it the second time the list still contains the previous requested items.

Comment: when you run it second time means? what you are exactly doing?

Comment: @abhijeet I am closing the browser and restarting the program via url or re running it from the ide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56393/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-richard-davy).

Comment: Its clearly a caching issue. Add no-cache headers to your page to tell the browser to not cache it.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing about this issue is that it wasn't anything to do with the request attribute variables. Since I was instantiating a list of objects in a class that list of objects was persisting and just being added to. I think this is mostly because I was using an ArrayList which is able to be appended to. Instead of re-writing the entire class to figure out some work around I included a try{}finally{} statement like so:

```
package com.ChattBank.controller;

    import com.ChattBank.business.Account;
    import com.ChattBank.business.Accounts;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    /**
     *
     * @author AARONS
     */
    public class AccountServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet AccountServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet AccountServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on                 the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

            if (action == null) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else if (action.equals("view")) {
                Accounts acct = new Accounts();
                ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList();
                try {
                    acct.setCustAccounts(request.getParameter("id"));
                    list.addAll(acct.getCustAccounts());
                    System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));

                    //This was moved into the try block itself
                    request.setAttribute("acctList", list);
               request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/accounts.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Accounts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                //This is the added finally statement with the clearAccounts method
                } finally {
                   acct.clearAccounts();
                }


            } 

        }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        String custId = request.getParameter("custID");

        if (action == null) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

The clear accounts method in the Accounts class was very very simple:

```
  /**
   * Clears the current array list of accounts 
   */
public void clearAccounts(){
    this.custAccounts.clear();
}
```